# iOS: Record audio below some certain frequency

Tags: ios, avaudiorecorder, avaudiosession, lowpass-filter

I am working on an app in which I have to perform recording from iPhone's microphone, but my requirement is to record only voice below some certain frequency. All other voice more than this frequency should not be record.

I know SO already has many post on this, but I couldn't find any helpful.

I find the frequency by using this code:-
http://www.ehow.com/how_12224909_detect-blow-mic-xcode.html

But I am getting trouble to avoid this frequency being recorded.

Can anyone suggest me how to do this or If any lib/open source is available. Any help on this will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should really read up on digital signal processing - what you want to achieve is for example does using a lowpass filter. Please show what you have tried and where your exact problem lies. Otherwise any answer would need to be very broad.

Answer (score 2):

First I would check if the microphone of the device can detect frequencies in your Band Width.
Second iOS comes with an amazing framework called [accelerate](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Accelerate/Reference/AccelerateFWRef/index.html) here you can find [vDSP](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Accelerate/Reference/vDSPRef/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009464) library (digital signal processing) with those functionalities:

- Vector and matrix arithmetic
- Fourier transforms
- Convolution, correlation, and window generation

Accelerate is very efficient set of functionalities, powerful and performant.
Your problem seems to be a matter of filtering (mostly).
Here a sample from Apple, [Using Fourier transform](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/vDSP_Programming_Guide/UsingFourierTransforms/UsingFourierTransforms.html).

Comment: Thanks... but I am not aware of all of this. Your keywords will help me to search on web. Thanks